# zeroclipboard element not working when located inside secondary/non-default jQuery tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

I've got a page with jQuery tabs, and I'm trying to link a div element inside a secondary tab with zeroclipboard. Unfortunately, it's not working because I suspect the secondary tab is initially hidden when the page is loaded.

The html is the following:

```
<span id="form" class="tabs tabs-normal grid100">

   <!-- HEADER BUTTONS -->
   <div class="row_btns_header">
      <button class="btn_neutral">Cancel</button>
      <button class="btn_primary last save">Save</button>     
   </div>

   <!-- TABS -->
   <div class="row">
      <ul id="tabs-list">
        <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#links">Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="#images">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#more">More..</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

   <!-- DEFAULT TAB -->
   <div id="blog" class="container">

   </div>

   <!-- LINKS TAB -->
   <div id="links" class="container">
        <div id="embed" style="position: relative">
           <a href="#">Copy into the clipboard</a>
        </div>
   </div>

   <!-- etc. -->
```

The javascript is:

```
$(".tabs").tabs();

$("#embed").zclip({
        path: "http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
        copy: "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
    });
```

zeroclipboard works correctly, if I move the #embed div inside the #blog div. I suspect this is because #blog is visible by default.

Any ideas what I need to do in order to get the zeroclipboard element to work when it's located inside a secondary non-default tab?

Much thanks.

Bardi

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is an old thread, but hopefully this helps someone out there.

I just had the same problem and the solution I came up with was to bind the creation of the zclip object to a mouseover event tied to the desired trigger button/link. Also, to prevent the script from reinitializing the zclip object each time a mouseover event occurs, just turn it off when it is first called. Here's an example:

The HTML:

```
<input type='text' value='Text being copied.'/> <input type='button' class='clipcopy' value='Copy'/>
```

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".clipcopy").on('mouseover', function(){

        //turn off this listening event for the element that triggered this
        $(this).off('mouseover');

         //initialize zclip
        $(this).zclip({
            path: "js/zclip/ZeroClipboard.swf",
            copy: function(){return $(this).prev().prop('value');}
         });

     });
 });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much man... It totally worked.. I was about to loose hope when this finally worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

The tabs plugin sets the tab panels to `display: none`, which means the Flash doesn't get started right away. You could try hacking it with CSS:

```
.container.ui-helper-hidden {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: -99999px;
}
```

This will override the `display: none` and instead position the panel off the screen - this way the content is loaded and the panel is measured, but won't be visible to the user. (This is the same way the `.ui-helper-hidden-accessible` used to work)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've looked at the code using Chrome's code inspector, and didn't see any of the tabs be assigned .ui-helper-hidden. Instead, I saw .ui-tabs-hidden, which I changed to the above:

.container.ui-tabs-hide { 
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: -99999px; 
}

This unfortunately hasn't worked. Only when I remove the 'left' property, resulting in the tabs being on top of each other, did zeroclipboard work when I clicked on the 'Copy to the clipboard' link.

Comment: Actually, it does appear to work, but seems to take a little while (at least 15-20 seconds and sometimes up to a minute) before #embed is replaced with swf Flash file? I've replaced the path of the .swf file to one on my own server, but to no avail. This isn't the case if it's located by default in the first tab.

Answer (score 0):

The point is initialize it on a mouseover event, I am use [jquery.clipboard](https://github.com/valeriansaliou/jquery.clipboard) and this also work

```
$("a.button-copy-shortcode").on('mouseover', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    //initialize clipboard
    $(this).clipboard({
        path: pluginDir+'/tonjoo-tom/assets/js/jquery.clipboard.swf',
        copy: function() {

            var shortcode = $(this).find('.shortcodeValue').text();

            return shortcode;
        }
    });
});
```