# zclip not work in jquery ui inactive tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, zclip

I am using [zclip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) in my asp.net webpage on jQuery UI dialog in jQuery UI tab. It works great in first tab which is active but it doesn't work when I add it to second tab and click second tab and clip copy button.

my markup is below:

```
<input type="text" id="txtCallStatus" class="disabled" 
    readonly="readonly" value="NOT SET" />
<a href="#" id="copy-dynamic" onclick="return false;">Copy status</a>
```

Js code is below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/recording/verifyUser",
    data: {
        ID: $("#ID").val(),
        PSSWD: $("#PSSWD").val(),
        ACCID: $("#ACCID").val(),
        PASSWDINT: $("#PASSWDINT").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == "success") {

            $('#dialog-AddCallRecording').dialog({ closeOnEscape: false });

            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
            $("#dialog-AddCallRecording").dialog({ 
                dialogClass: 'transparent', 
                modal: true 
            });
            $("#dialog-AddCallRecording").dialog("open");

            // The link with ID "copy-description" will copy
            // the text of the paragraph with ID "description"
            $('a#copy-dynamic').zclip({
                path: '../../Content/Zclip/ZeroClipboard.swf',
                copy: function () { return $('input#txtCallStatus').val(); }
            });

            // The link with ID "copy-dynamic" will copy the current value
            // of a dynamically changing input with the ID "dynamic"

        }
        else {
            $("#dialog-user-login").dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
            $("#dialog-user-login").dialog("open");
        }
    }
});
```

In success, after dialogue is open, I am initializing the zclip.

Please suggest solution to it. Thanks

Comment: So you have $('input#txtCallStatus').val(); this in both tabs?

Comment: no on second tab only

Comment: Use developer tools and make sure if zclip div and embeded flash file is present in the source? if you are using partial view try reffering jquery and zclip js file into it, so that when partial view is rendering they can make use of it.

Comment: See this answer worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559100/zeroclipboard-element-not-working-when-located-inside-secondary-non-default-jque